# Is it possible to send GA events from the server side using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd like to integrate Google Analytics API with Node.js using the npm package by google called `googleapis`

I know it is possible to **read** the analytics on the server side. However, I'd like to know if it would be possible to **send** GA-events on the server side as well using node.js?

Comment: Curious, what events would you need to send server side instead of client side?

Comment: Let's take an example. I have a button, which when I hit, it sends an event to the server saying i'm a user from 'X' country. I want to be able to handle that on the server side and send an event using GA which will increase the counter for the number of people visiting from that country

Comment: Why can't you do it on the client side? As other people have pointed out, in theory you can do it, but GA is geared for measuring client interactions with websites (and you pointed out that you want to send an event when a user clicks a button - a client side interaction) and is done via a client-side script. If you don't have the user's country when the button is clicked, make an AJAX request to your server to get some info and when it returns fire a GA event on the client.

Answer (score 1):

The foundation for GA is the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). It can be used to send hits back to GA. One thing to note is that if you want to report on acquisition or users around those events, you would need to find a way to pass that information along in the MP hit. This is because GA will see the hits originating from your server/IP instead of your user's computers/IP.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically, since the GA calls are effectively only HTTP calls, you can of course send them from the server side.

Another question is whether this is reasonable (and allowed by the t&c of GA).